# AWS S3 rest api signature

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can someone please help me with calculating the [AWS_SIGNATURE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html) in bash

Here is the GET I am trying to do:

```
curl -k \
-X GET \
-H "Host: ${AWS_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" \
-H "Date: Tue, 27 Nov 2018 11:20:00 +0200" \
-H "Authorization: AWS ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}:${AWS_SIGNATURE}" \
"https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/${AWS_BUCKET_NAME}/?list-type=2"
```

Comment: It is inside the documentation, so what is your actual problem?

Comment: My apologies, I meant to say Can someone please help me with calculating the AWS_SIGNATURE in bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install openssl and base64 encoder to create the signature.

Assume you supply value for each $variable

```
Signature=`echo -n $StringToSign | openssl sha1 -hmac $YourSecretAccessKeyID | base64`
```